# Silverlight how to create attached properties that can only be placed in children

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

In Silverlight (or WPF for that matter) you can something like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeKey">...</DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="AnotherKey">...</DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="OneMoreKey">...</DataTemplate>
    <UserControl.Resources>
...
```

Now when I have my own custom control which takes a collection of DataTemplates.

I cannot set x:Key on those DataTemplates, why not? (first question!)

Now I think it has something to do that my collection does not inherit from ResourceDictionary.

If that is the answer HOW do I create an attached property which can only be set on Children (DataTemplates) of my own custom control?

I found `AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType` but I cannot find it for Silverlight...

Comment: `x:Key` is not an attached property (it's a special case in the XAML parser), so the fact that you can only use it when defining resources will not help you on your quest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that x:Key is for Resources.
What is this attached property for? You might be going about it the wrong way.

Comment: How do you intend to use it though? An attached property will not do anything unless you pick it up from somewhere, so even if it was placed on another element, it should never be looked for or acted upon on that element. So I wouldn't bother try to lock it down to just being available on DataTemplates.